# get range input and scroll the given value

Tags: jquery, input, scroll

I want to have an input range slider on my website, and each time it gets an input, the value will be used to scroll the website.

This is all I have. I've tested if the value comes trough.

JS:

```
$('#slider').on('input', function(){
  var val = $(this).val()
  window.scrollTop(val);
});
```

HTML:

```
     <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

I thought that this has to work, because click events and animate functions also work with this function.

Comment: Its should be work.

Answer (score 0):

input event works when you input any not empty value which is different from the current value then it fires.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I replaced

```
window.scrollTop(val);
```

with

```
$("html, body").scrollTop(val);
```